# Bilinearity of covariance, $Cov(\sum a_iY_i, \sum K_iY_i)$

Tags: statistics

My textbook says that $$Cov(\sum a_iY_i, \sum K_iY_i)=\sum a_iK_iCov(Y_i,Y_i).$$

And so it concludes that $$Cov(\sum a_iY_i, \sum K_iY_i)=\sum a_iK_i Var(Yi)=\sigma^2\sum a_iK_i.$$

But I think it should be $$Cov(\sum a_iY_i, \sum K_jY_j)=\sum_i \sum_j a_iK_jCov(Y_i,Y_j).$$

Which one is right and why?

In addition, it is written that $a_i=\cfrac 1n, K_i=\cfrac{(x_i-x)}{S_{xx}}$.

Are these informations related to my quesition?

Any help would be appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are right, now if (for example) the $Y_i$ are independent, then $\mathrm{Cov}(Y_i,Y_j)=0$ for $i\neq j$

Comment: I think it should be $$Cov(\sum a_iY_i, \sum K_iY_i)=\sum \sum a_iK_jCov(Y_i,Y_j).$$ unless you talk about uncorrelated RVs.

Comment: Very surprised to hear that such statement is made in a text book. Please avoid such books.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Your feedbacks really helped me. I hope you guys have a great day.